# Parse.com push notification not filtering channels for Android

Tags: android, parse-platform, push-notification

In my chat app I use Parse.com for Push notification. When app launches it subscribes to parse.com Push for its own channel like this

```
ParsePush.subscribeInBackground("users_" + userId);
```

The problem is that parse.com should exclude user who sent the message from the target users channels. So user shouldn't receive push notification for its own message. I checked parse.com dashboard, it tells me that my user channel is not included in broadcast for my message. But I still get push notifications for my own messages.

From Parse.com dashboard for message:

```
TARGETING
channels includes any of "users_8", "users_69", "users_121", "users_53", "users_76", "users_94" or "users_153"
deviceType is any of "ios", "android", "winphone" or "js"
SENDING TIME
February 5th, 2015 at 3:19 PM

EXPIRATION
None

FULL TARGET
{ "channels": { "$in": [ "users_8", "users_69", "users_121", "users_53", "users_76", "users_94", "users_153" ] }, "deviceType": { "$in": [ "ios", "android", "winphone", "js" ] } }

FULL DATA
{ "sound": "chime", "badge": "Increment", "group_id": 96, "content-available": 1, "type": "message", "alert": "group nikon: vjvuvu" }
```

Answer (score 0):

Got this answer from Parse tech support:

This is partly caused by the data model you chose. Installations are not meant to be a replacement for users, it should more be a User collection that has installations associated with them.

However you should be able to make this work by build your query as follows and based on these two assumptions:

1. Assume the sending user has the objectId V0A5U2fx7H
2. Assume the message was sent to the chat room users_69

So you now query for where 'channels contains string users_69' and objectId does not equal V0A5U2fx7H, which is the ID of the sending user.